# HTML Drodown Navbar - external links not showing navbar

Tags: php, css, navbar

i am using following guide to create a navbar on my website:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp

When i now add links to the href:

> ```
>  <div class="dropdown-content">
>   <a href="/content/mycontent.php">Link 1</a>
>   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
>   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
> </div>
> ```

... and click on Link 1 the content of "mycontent.php" is shown in fullscreen, but the navbar is gone. What is simplest and best way, so that mycontent.php is shown and also the nvbar is always shown?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Your mycontent.php page does not have the navbar itself. You have to understand, that loading a php script into the browser renders your screen blank and build it up according to the content of the script. That's why the script itself has to contain the navbar

The best way to include it, that you put the navbar into a separate file and than include it as a partial or element like so:

```
<?php
//this is a header on every page
require('partials/navbar.view.php')
?>
// this is the body of your code
--> the other content you have on the page
```

I think that's it. Reading Your question I would recommend, that You should read more about the lifecycle of a php request because You seem to miss the basic understanding of it. Maybe You should watch PHP for beginners series on YouTube made by Laracasts. It's free.

Comment: okay, thanks for your feedback, but with DHTMLX it is for example possible to create a tabbar with tabs. And a TAB can have a link to an external page, that will be shown under the tabbar.

Comment: As I see, the DHTMLX is a JavaScript library so it is an 'another league', not PHP. Maybe the integration of a PHP code and JS is a bit complicated but it can be managed with some experience. As I have written before, the 'PHP modules', or PHP partials have to be present in the page You are directing the browser with clicking the link. That has to solve the problem. Maybe You should give the code of both HTML pages, to have a chance for solving the program.